# A Forgot Password Functionality in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing a forgot password functionality in ASP.NET MVC4 but can't successfully allow users to reset their password.

My MVC application displays a RECOVER password link on the login page for users who have forgotten their passwords.The first part of the application works fine and a mail is sent to the user ...but the later part to allow users to change their password is not working .

This is my forgot password controller action method :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string UserName)
{
    //Check user existence
    var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);

    if (user == null)
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "User Not exist.";
    }
    else
    {
        //Generate password token
        var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(UserName);

        //Create URL with above token
        var resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { un = UserName, rt = token }, "http") + "'>Reset Password</a>";

        //Get user emailid
        UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
        var emailid = (from i in db.UserProfiles
                       where i.UserName == UserName
                       select i.EmailId).FirstOrDefault();

        //Send mail
        string subject = "Password Reset Token";
        string body = "<b>Please find the Password Reset Token</b><br/>" + resetLink;

        //Edit it
        try
        {
            SendEMail(emailid, subject, body);
            TempData["Message"] = "Mail Sent.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "Error occured while sending email." + ex.Message;
        }

    }

    return View();
}
```

This is my forgot password view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Forgot Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("User Name", new { @for = "UserName" })
                @Html.TextBox("UserName")
                <span style="color:red;">@TempData["Message"]</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Recover" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

The forgot password view page allows user to enter their username.
I get the username and email id and build URL and send mail to the user.
This part runs successfully.
Now user is redirected to my reset password page.
Here I wish to allow user to enter a new password and update my database.
How should my reset controller action and view page be?

I couldn't even display the old password using the following controller action: 
(Where Am I going wrong ?)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string un, string rt)
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

    //Get userid of received username
    var userid = (from i in db.UserProfiles
                  where i.UserName == un
                  select i.UserId).FirstOrDefault();


    var yrpassword = (from k in db.webpages_Memberships
                      where k.UserId == userid
                      select k.Password);

    TempData["Message"] = "This is your user name" + un; 
    TempData["Message"] = "This is your user-id" + userid;
    TempData["Message"] = "This is your user password" + yrpassword;

    return View();
}
```

This is the current view page of reset password controller action :

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.webpages_Membership

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset Password";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

<section id="loginForm">

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Password Reset Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>                           
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>        
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login") You can now login to your account.
            </li>
        </ol>
}
</section>
```

I know it requires an update query but somehow I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Give the method and controller name in your beginform method to execute the method. Do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourMethod", "Controller"))
{
   <legend>Password Reset Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>           

    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```